# ubuntu wont run because windows cant load after i reboot my computer

Tags: 12.04, boot, reboot, compatibility, disk-management

i recently downloaded ubuntu and after installing it and rebooting it the computer tells me windows failed to laod components have been erased or missing and insert your installation disk and press repair

so what do i do is there another way out of this problem i currently run windows 8 os
on a hp pavilion with a a4 amd processor at 2500 mhz and i downloaded and installed the 32 bit version of ubuntu linux? please help if I have to buy the installation disk I will but I want to know if there are any other options.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you've got a problem with the bootloader (the program that boots the operating system for you. Things can get confused when installing multiple operating systems. Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) for info on fixing your bootloader.

Comment: I did what the link said and there is still a problem.

Comment: The same problem or a different one?